# List which contains 10000 items, how to insert this list in cloud_firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
var list = List<int>.generate(10000, (i) => i = i+1);
Map<String, String> Data = <String,String>{
    '1': '',
    '2': '',
    '3': '',
    '4': '',
    '5': '',
    '6': '',
    '7': '',
    '8': '',
    '9': '',
    '10': '',
  };
```

Like this, I want to insert the all 10000 values in the cloud firestore in a single document using flutter, How to write query for this??

Comment: Is this going into one document? Multiple documents? What exactly do these doucment(s) look like?  Please edit your question to be clear.

Comment: for each user, there is one document of 10000 fields

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: I don't know the logic to insert the list in firestore, if i try like i have mentioned i have to write 10000 fields but that is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to write 10,000 fields to a single document or an array of 10,000 elements to a single document. Two rather different things.

Writing a single document with a single array field with a lot of elements you could do this:

```
var data = {'arrayField': longList}; 
db.collection('myCollection').doc().set(data)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Document added');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
    });
```

Firestore documentation is also very good. Here is the page about adding data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

Store the list of data in a variable and then using the below code you can insert the list in database:-

```
DocumentReference documentReference=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('yourCollectioName').doc();
      documentReference.set({
        'id':documentReference.id,
        'data':FieldValue.arrayUnion([a]),//replace a with your list variable
      }).catchError((e)=>print(e));
```

But take care that maximum size of a document can be `1 MiB`. Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use array field in firestre**

```
var list = List<int>.generate(10000, (i) => i = i+1);
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('COLLECTION_NAME')
.doc("YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID")
.update({cart': FieldValue.arrayUnion([list])
```

Change `COLLECTION_NAME` to your `collection name` and `YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID` to your required `Document id`